# How can I play an iOS system sound and cancel the callback

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app where I play a system sound to indicate to the user that they can begin recording. I currently use the code below.

```
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(1117) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.setupRecordingViews()

        }
        // beging recording 
    }
```

However the user could cancel wanting to record something once this function has begun and I need to a way to be able to cancel it in order to stop my UI changing to begin recording.

Any ideas how I could do this using a system sound? is there a way I can add an observer or delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understand the issue, but just before you call `setupRecordingViews()` could you check a `self.didCancel` flag?

In your handler for whatever cancel button you have you would just set that:

```
self.didCancel = true
```

Comment: thanks Dave - realised that I was trying to overcomplicate the situation when a flag was all that was needed